# Menu links are not displaying below the menu button

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, display

I can not figure this out.  I have a horizontal navigation with sublinks within the menu buttons that are not displaying under the buttons.  Please help.  Thank you.

```
<!--Click dropdown menu-->
    <nav class="container">
            <button class="dropbtn" onclick="dropFile()">File</button>
            <div id="myDropFile" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="" >link 1</a>
                <a href="">link 2</a>
                <a href="">link 3</a>
            </div>
            <button class="dropbtn" onclick="dropEdit()">Edit</button>
            <div id="myDropEdit" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="" >link 4</a>
                <a href="">link 5</a>
                <a href="">link 6</a>
            </div>
            <button class="dropbtn" onclick="dropView()">View</button>
            <div id="myDropView" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="" >link 7</a>
                <a href="">link 8</a>
                <a href="">link 9</a>
            </div>
    </nav>
```

Then my css is:

```
.container {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
font-family: Arial;
}

.container a {
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

.dropbtn {
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 16px;    
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
} 

.show {
display: block;
```

}

The menus links display all under the first menu button instead of being displayed under each particular button.  I have tried everything and read all the previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a rule that affects the sibling `div` from the `button` you hover on.  Something like:

```
.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content, .dropdown-content:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  right: inherit;
  margin-left: -60px;  
}
```

However, the positioning of the drop-down will need to be modified.  I'll see if I can put together a running example

**UPDATED**:

Adjusted positioning as well (updated rule above). See **running sample** below

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content, .dropdown-content:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  right: inherit;
  margin-left: -60px;  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--Click dropdown menu-->
<nav class="container">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="dropFile()">File</button>
  <div id="myDropFile" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="">link 1</a>
    <a href="">link 2</a>
    <a href="">link 3</a>
  </div>
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="dropEdit()">Edit</button>
  <div id="myDropEdit" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="">link 4</a>
    <a href="">link 5</a>
    <a href="">link 6</a>
  </div>
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="dropView()">View</button>
  <div id="myDropView" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="">link 7</a>
    <a href="">link 8</a>
    <a href="">link 9</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```